# Representation theory of finite groups searching for example that does not exist in char(K)=0?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am searching for an example of a finite group $G$ and an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic $p$, s.t. $p \nmid |G| $ with an irreducible representation $\rho : G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ and $p | \operatorname{dim}(V) < \infty$.

The question did come up since for $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$ we have the relation $\operatorname{dim}(V) \mid |G|$, so an example like above does not exist.

But how does it look like if we have an assumption like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K$ is algebraically closed and $char(K)$ does not divide $|G|$ then the irreducible representations over $K$ have the same dimensions as over $\mathbb{C}$.   In particular the dimensions must divide $|G|$ and therefore not be divisible by $char(K)$.

Comment: Is your statement true? Do you have any source to look the theorem up?

Comment: Probably any book on modular representation theory of finite groups will have it? If you start with a representation in characteristic zero you can always find an integral form (defined over some ring of integers) and then reduce modulo $p$ to get a representation in characteristic $p$.  Going the other direction, given a representation in characteristic $p$ which is projective you can lift it to a representation in characteristic zero -- and if $p \not\vert |G|$ then every representation is projective and therefore lifts. These maps let you match up the irreducible representations.

Comment: Does the reducing process and lifting process inherits irreducibility? And I looked up on Humphreys modular rep.theory book, but could not find any result like that (but I maybe overlooked it).

Comment: If $p$ divides the order of $G$ and you reduce an irreducible representation from characteristic zero to characteristic $p$ then typically it will be reducible, and understanding the multiplicities of the characteristic $p$ irreducibles in this is notoriously hard. These multiplicities make up what is known as the decomposition matrix.  Going the other direction: irreducible representations in characteristic $p$ may not lift to characteristic zero, but if they do lift then they stay irreducible as if there were a subrepresentation in characteristic zero you could reduce it mod $p$.